# Deploy mongodb replicaset servers with Docker on different physical servers

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to deploy a mongodb replicaset using docker.
I managed to do it on a same server by executing this :

```
docker run -d --expose 27017 --name mongodbmycompany1 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsmycompa
docker run -d --expose  27017 --name mongodbmycompany2 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsacommeassure
docker run -d --expose 27017 --name mongodbmycompany3 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsacommeassure

MONGODB1=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mongodbmycompany1)
MONGODB2=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mongodbmycompany2)
MONGODB3=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' mongodbmycompany3)

echo $MONGODB1
echo $MONGODB2
echo $MONGODB3

echo "Mongodb Replicaset init"
docker exec mongodbmycompany1 mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/mycompany --eval 'if(!rs.conf()) {     rs.initiate(); cfg = rs.conf(); cfg.members[0].host = "'$MONGODB1':27017"; rs.reconfig(cfg); rs.add("'$MONGODB2':27017"); rs.add("'$MONGODB3':27017"); } rs.status();'
```

It's working as expected. My replicaset is initialized and my mongodb resultset config contains my 3 servers identified by their internal IP address.
It's not perfect as I'd prefer to use servers names but I didn't manage to do it.
Docker only populate each /etc/hosts file with servers names passed at image launch with --link parameter. If i add a new server while others are running. Those servers won't ping the new server.

Now I have another question. In production, having a lot of Mongodb docker image running on a same physical server is possible but it's not safe :
- if my physical server falls down, i lose all my Mongodb replicas and my service is down
- if my physical server uses internal storage, all my docker images use the same disk... and I'm going to have IO problems.

So my question is : **How can I deploy many mongodb replicas on multiple physical servers ? How those mongodb replicas can communicate with each others (primary and secondaries servers can change) while they are on different servers or even on different datacenters ?**

Comment: What is exactly your problem in doing this? What about usign OpenStack to schedule the Docker container on your several physical nodes?

Comment: I'm going to have a look at OpenStack to solve the problem. Do you have a document in which OpenStack helps managing mongodb docker files in order to have a replicaset distributed on many servers ?

Comment: No, I just used OpenStack to instatiate Docker for purpose different from creating a MongoDB replica set.

Comment: You need a virtual LAN that acts as a single discoverable network bridge for your docker container. Have a look at coreos/flannel. This will solve your networking issue with least effort.

Answer (score 16):

Let's assume:

1. you have 3 different docker hosts (servers), with IPs `10.1.1.101`, `10.1.1.102`, `10.1.1.103`
2. want to deploy a single replica set called `rsacommeassure`
3. `Dockerfile`s for mongodb expose port 27017
4. all servers are in a trusted zone and can talk to each other

First let's start mongodb containers on each server (`10.1.1.101 ~$` is used for command prompt):

```
10.1.1.101 ~$ docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodbmycompany1 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsacommeassure
10.1.1.102 ~$ docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodbmycompany2 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsacommeassure
10.1.1.103 ~$ docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodbmycompany3 dockerfile/mongodb mongod --replSet rsacommeassure
```

`-p 27017:27017` exposes port 27017 on the host IP so mongo is accessible on servers' host IP address.

Then you need to initiate the replica set, so just run this against a mongodb container (I'll pick server1 here):

```
your_laptop ~$ > mongo --host 10.1.1.101 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
> rs.initiate()
> cfg = rs.conf()
> cfg.members[0].host = "10.1.1.101:27017"
> rs.reconfig(cfg)
> rs.add("10.1.1.102:27017")
> rs.add("10.1.1.103:27017") 
> rs.status();
```

The IPs are local but it works with global as well as long as the servers can talk to each other (VPN, firewall, DMZ, whatever). Btw you should consider [security](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/security/) carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot @milan

Comment: That's very useful. I would like to ask if you think it would be also feasible to connect two docker containers with a real mongo instance. I really need to synch a 450GB db from a remote host with replica sets running on my containers located on another physical server.

Comment: @sparaflAsh sounds like another question, possibly for serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks. I will probably post there to ask some hint on best practice. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Replica Set on different physical servers using docker-machine and virtual box as a driver:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox server1
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox server2
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox server3
```

Open 3 different terminals, in each

```
$(Terminal1) eval "$(docker-machine env server1)"
$(Terminal2) eval "$(docker-machine env server2)"
$(Terminal3) eval "$(docker-machine env server3)"
```

In each terminal:

```
$(Terminal1) docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongoClient1 mongo mongod --replSet r1
$(Terminal2) docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongoClient2 mongo mongod --replSet r1
$(Terminal3) docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongoClient3 mongo mongod --replSet r1
```

Go in VirtualBox -> on each environment(server1,server2,server3) -> Setting -> Network -> Adapter 1 -> Port Forwarding. Create a new rule Protocol TCP, Host Port - 27017, Guest Port - 27017, leave Host Ip and Guest Ip empty

Now restart all the environments, you can do this from the VirtualBox or from the terminal, from terminal just run:

```
$(Terminal1) docker-machine restart server1
$(Terminal2) docker-machine restart server2
$(Terminal3) docker-machine restart server3
```

Restart the containers:

```
$(Terminal1) docker start mongoClient1
$(Terminal2) docker start mongoClient2
$(Terminal3) docker start mongoClient3
```

Now the containers should be running, you can check them by running 
$ docker ps in each terminal

Get into the first container's(or another) Mongo Shell

```
$(Terminal1) docker exec -it mongoClient1 mongo
// now we are in the Mongo Shell
$(Mongo Shell) rs.initiate()
$(Mongo Shell) cfg = rs.conf()
$(Mongo Shell) cfg.members[0].host = <server1's Ip Address>
// you should get server1's Ip Address by running $ docker-machine ls, mine was 192.168.99.100
$(Mongo Shell) rs.reconfig(cfg)
$(Mongo Shell Primary) rs.add("<server2's Ip Address>:27017")
// now we added a Secondary
$(Mongo Shell Primary) rs.add("<server3's Ip Address>:27017", true)
// now we added an Arbiter
$(Mongo Shell Primary) use planes
// now we create a new database
$(Mongo Shell Primary) db.tranporters.insert({name:'Boeing'})
// create a new collection
$(Mongo Shell Primary) db.tranporters.find()
// we obtain the inserted plane
```

To connect to a Secondary, you can either:

```
$(Terminal2) docker exec -it mongoClient2 mongo planes
// or
$(Mongo Shell Primary) db = connect ("<server2's Ip Address>:27017/planes")
```

Now we are in the Mongo Shell of a Secondary

```
$(Mongo Shell Secondary) rs.slaveOk()
// to allow readings from the Shell
$(Mongo Shell Secondary)db.tranporters.find()
// should return inserted plane
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use "[Weave - the Docker network](https://github.com/zettio/weave)" to resolve your problem easily.

Weave creates an overlay network that joins containers on different hosts, even at different cloud providers. Weave also supplies a DNS service that lets you find containers by name within the Weave network.

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Just put the essential parts of the link in your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here stop already running instances
docker stop m1 m2 m3
#Cleanup of the volumes
docker rm -f m1 m2 m3

# Start MongoDB services optimised for faster startup
docker run  -dP --name m1 mongo mongod --replSet "r1" --noprealloc --smallfiles --nojournal --syncdelay 0 
docker run  -dP --name m2 mongo mongod --replSet "r1" --noprealloc --smallfiles --nojournal --syncdelay 0 
docker run  -dP --name m3 mongo mongod --replSet "r1" --noprealloc --smallfiles --nojournal --syncdelay 0

export M1_ADDRESS=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' m1`
export M2_ADDRESS=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' m2`
export M3_ADDRESS=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' m3`

docker exec m1 mongo --eval "rs.initiate();"
docker exec m1 mongo --eval "cfg = rs.conf(); cfg.members[0].host = '$M1_ADDRESS:27017'; rs.reconfig(cfg);"
docker exec m1 mongo --eval "rs.add('$M2_ADDRESS:27017');rs.add('$M3_ADDRESS:27017')"

# Check if everything is fine.
docker exec m1 mongo --eval "rs.status();"
```

Answer (score -2):

I scripted a docker-image that sets up a mongodb replicaSet for any number of containers and automates scaling as you add more containers. check out the github [github repo](https://github.com/rollymaduk/mongo-replica)  or [docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/r/rollymaduk/mongo-replica/)

***Use Docker Compose***

setup your docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  <your_service_name>:
     image: rollymaduk/mongo-replica:local
     environment:
       REPLICA_NAME: "<your_replica_name>"
     volumes:
     -  /var/config:/var/config
```

run in command line

```
docker-compose up
```

scale up to more containers

```
docker-compose scale <your_service_name>=3
```

**Docker Cloud**
To deploy mongo-db replicaSet using docker-cloud, set up a stack
file

*stack.yml: stack file not requiring shared volumes*

```
<service_name>:
  image: rollymaduk/mongo-replica:cloud
  deployment_strategy: high_availability
  target_num_containers: 3
  environment:
    REPLICA_NAME: <your_replica_name>
    DOCKERCLOUD_AUTH: <your_docker_auth_key>
```

*stack.yml: stack file requiring shared volume*

```
<service_name>:
  image: rollymaduk/mongo-replica:local
  deployment_strategy: high_availability
  target_num_containers: 3
  volumes:
    - /var/config:/var/config
  environment:
    REPLICA_NAME: <your_replica_name>
```

using docker-cloud cli run in command line (If stack file does not exist in cloud)

```
docker-cloud stack create --name <your_stack_name> -f <your_stack_file>

docker-cloud stack start <your_stack_name>
```

using docker-cloud cli run in command line (If stack file already exists in cloud)

```
docker-cloud stack update -f <your_stack_file> <your_stack_name>

docker-cloud stack redeploy <your_stack_name>
```

> *Important: you must specify a shared volume and mount it to the container's
>   config directory [default: /var/config ] the example below mounts a host
>   directory /var/config to the container's config volume.
>
>   You can use any of the docker recommended ways of sharing volumes between
>   containers i.e mounting a host directory or data volume container),just
>   you specify the correct path for the config volume (/var/config).*
>
> _to change default config directory use the environment variable 
>   --CONFIG_DIR to setup your container. Make sure to update host volume
>   path to reflect your new --CONFIG_DIR name_